# Search for specific entry in Get-Aduser - directreports

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of user samaccount names that I need query for the manager attribute. Then I need to query the results (DN) of the manger account for the accounts directs reports, there will be multiple on each account. Then I need to search for direct report that contains "(admin)" in it (in the DN). I need that full DN and none that dont match (there should only be one)

My input is currently a get-aduser for testing. Everything works up to the "where"

I think I'm very close I just cant seem to get the last step

```
Get-Aduser -filter {cn -like "ea8f"} -Properties directreports -server domain.com | 
select-Object -ExpandProperty directreports | Where $_.directreports -Contains "(admin)"
```

```
Where-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:2 char:57
+ ... Object -ExpandProperty directreports | Where $_.directreports -Contai ...
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Comment: There is no AD user attribute `directreports`.An AD user does have a `Manager` attribute though that contains the DistinghuihedName of the manager if it is set at all.. The manager's user object contains a `directReports` property that contains references to all user objects that have their manager properties set to this distinguished name. Furthermore, if `"ea8f"` is the SamAccountName you obtained from your list, use `-Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'ea8f'"`

Comment: Just being pedantic, but `-like` and `-eq` have the same outcome if no wildcards are in use @Theo

Comment: Direct Reports is not a attribute, its generated on request. Manager is a backlinked attribute that is used to create it

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That is not what I'm saying. The OP is mentioning he/she has a list of SamAccountNames, that is why I'm suggesting to compare this literally in the filter using `eq`.

Comment: I was replying to the guy above you.. did I do that wrong?

Comment: @SysAdminADGuy It's the other way around: [`manager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-manager) is just a plain attribute. [`directReports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-directreports) is a back-link.

Comment: Getting a bit confused now. You ask for getting the Manager property of the users you have in the list and using **their** Manager DN, get the DirectReports where the string `(admin)` can be found. Is that correct? Or are you trying to get the DirectReport of each user from the list as your code suggests?

Comment: 1 Find or import list of SamACcounts
2. Take each SAMaccount and grab the managers attribute
3. Search for the managers account and its direct reports
4. Search listed direct reports and return only the direct report that contains “(admin)”, nothing else.. just the DN

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have not tested this at the moment, but I think this may work:

```
# read the users SamAccountNames from the file and loop through
$result = Get-Content -Path 'THE LIST.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    # get the Manager attribute
    $managerDN = Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties Manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manager
    if ($managerDN) {
        # if set, use Get-ADUser on the manager DN and try and find the DirectReports that contain the string "(admin)"
        Get-ADUser -Identity $managerDN -Properties DirectReports | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports | 
            Where-Object { $_ -match '\(admin\)'} | 
            ForEach-Object {
                # output this DN
                $directReports
            }
    }
}

# output to console
$result
```

Comment: Thanks. I end up using a lot of ideas from your script,

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me 100%, thanks to everyone who contributed I used something from everyone.

```
$input = Get-Content -Path $path 
$results = @()
#Process each account
ForEach ($user in $input) 
    {
    $current = get-aduser -Filter {samaccountname -like $user} -server $server -Properties Directreports |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports | 
    Where-Object { $_ -match '\(admin\)'}
        $dr = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $dr | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SAM -Value $user
        $dr | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Password -Value "z,7'*FBU+"
        $dr | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetOU -Value $current.Substring($current.IndexOf('OU='))
        $dr
        $results += $dr
    }

$results
```